# Why is it important to update aggregate instance in combination with eventSourcing

Tags: architecture, cqrs, event-sourcing

i just try to unterstand the Dataflow inside an CQRS Application. 
I understand a big percentages of the opportunities but in one Point are some Questionmarks for me.

Scenario: CQRS with Eventsourcing.

After you handled the command in your Aggregate you fire the Events.

Now, my question is: Why i have to apply the Event again in my aggregate.

```
public void Apply(TabOpened e)
{
    open = true;
}
```

So it looks for me following process

1. Send Command
2. Validate Command in Aggregate
3. Send Event from Aggreate/Commandhandler
4. Build Aggregate Instance from Eventstream
5. Apply Event to the newly updated Aggregate
6. Store the new Event to Eventstream
7. Destroy the instance again

When the User wants to see the updated Aggregate there is following Dataflow in my Opinion

1. Request specific Aggregate
2. Use Read-Model to get the newest Version of Aggregate
3. Watch Aggregate

Now my question is: What is the advantage of apply the Event again to the freshly builded Aggregate. There is now validation again. This must be useless work..

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize:
when applying a command you typically load the aggregate. then you want to change the aggregate's state which means you add an event. i believe your question is: why do you apply the event to your aggregate and not just append the event to the event store, becaue you will ditch the aggregate afterwards anyhow?

is this what you mean?

it basically just validates that what you will write to the event store can and will be applied correctly when you reload the aggregate the next time. als there might be multiple steps to take when processing the command which is changing the aggregate. the first step might change the state and change the output of the second step.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is exact the senseof my question. In my opinion the difference of event and Command is, that events not get validet.  And in your process the comand updates the Aggregate? This broke some CQRS rules in my understanding..

Comment: the command initiates the change. that is what i meant. inside the aggregate you update the state by applying events

Comment: But then there is only a benefit if you store the aggregate to a local cache. If you every time build from eventsource this step is not necessary? in theory..

Comment: no not really. there are 2 reasons why you want to apply the events to your local instance:

you validate that you can apply the event later on when reloading. if you just saved the event to the event stream without checking who knows if it can be replayed when loading. maybe it broke your aggregate's state.

also you might do 2 things inside 1 commandhandler. you dont want to reload the aggregate from the event store twice. but you do need the updated state for the second action you are doing

Comment: ok. the first argument with the "technical validation" of the event is understandable. But do i follow the cqrs rules if i have to update the state of my aggregate to successfull operate a command. That seems to be an bad relation between commands and events. In my understanding events have to be applyed after all event belonging commands are successfull validated..

Comment: yeah you always need an objects actual state. imagine you have a aggregate customer which has the customer info and all the orders for that customer. you might have a command which creates an order but because of the state of the customer it might not be allowed (imagine there are limits like how many orders per day are allowed). now imagine you do multiple of these actions during the process of 1 command... imagine the command would add 2 orders and you want to accept whats possible. if you just use the initial state when adding both orders the second would be accepted.

Comment: That is an comprehensibily example. I think i got it. Thanks for you indulgcene and your input! It helps to unterstand this interesting architecture!

Comment: no problem! an accepted answer would be appreciated btw :)

it is a very interesting architecture. it does have its problems but when used for the right problem its a very powerful  way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, my question is: Why i have to apply the Event again in my aggregate.

Because you want the local copy of the representation of the aggregate to match what you have written you your persistent store.

Consider the following sequence

1. I send a command to you.
2. You send an acknowledgement of that command to me.
3. ???
4. I send a query to you.
5. You send a query-response to me.

A property we want your service to have: the query-response in step 5 should be the same, whether step three is a *no-op* or a *service restart*.

This property is desirable whether or not you are using "event sourcing" as your persistence mechanism for communicating state from one service instance to the next.

> So it looks for me following process
>
> 2. Validate Command in Aggregate

There are really two different forms of validation that you should be tracking.  The first is the question of whether or not your command is well-formed; do all of the fields in the message have the right shape, are all of the required fields present, and so on.  These are all checks that you can do *without considering* the current state of the aggregate.

Is this command allowed when the aggregate is in it's current state is a separate idea.

> 3. Send Event from Aggreate/Commandhandler

Events should be written to the event stream before they are visible outside of the model (your step 6).

> 7. Destroy the instance again

Why are you doing that?  You certainly *can* evict the aggregate instance from the local cache; after all, you have all of the events you need to recover its state available in the stream.  But it isn't required.

Comment: Okay Thanks. That are valuable input for my understanding. Thank you!